# Projects are not showing up in add references Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have had the strangest thing that happen to me today, I went to start adding a new repository to `visualstudio.com` and add a project it gave me some trouble and told me to clone the repository. i did. after that I went on not thinking anything about it but when I went to add a reference to a new project it doesn't show up. [image: Add Reference]

I have tried to check many other projects and all are doing the same thing. so i googled it and found not much other than someone saying to reset import and export setting which i tried and still no luck. Does anyone have any ideas why this would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the `Shared Projects` submenu. You don't have any Shared Projects, that's why nothing is showing up. You have to go into the `Project` submenu on the left:

[image]

Comment: @JamTay317 Don't worry, I also got confused the first time I used it :/